# How do I output Linked List which holds objects using java.util.ListIterator?

Tags: java

Hi I got this problem with I am not sure how to deal with... I have a Linked List which stores Objects which works fine. But now I am trying to display the content of the linked list using iterator and I understand that wont be as simple as

```
ListIterator<String> iterator = LibraryUser.listIterator();  


iterator = LibraryUser.listIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext())
 System.out.println(iterator.next());
```

because of the type... Is there way to do this ?

OH RIGHT!  I need to override toString don't i...

Comment: Whats wrong? by the way don't initialize iterator twice.

Comment: Is `LibraryUser` an object or a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you know is that LibraryUser contains instances of `Object` (that is, you don't know that they are `String` instances), you can use:

```
ListIterator<Object> iterator = LibraryUser.listIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(iterator.next()));
}
```

or, more simply:

```
for (Object item : theList) {
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(item));
}
```

Comment: Yea I see what you doing here but this is what I get 
linkedlist.User@16ad9f5d
linkedlist.User@60b99e4c
linkedlist.User@3a47c130

The thing is the list hold 2 strings (first name and surname) and a number

Comment: @user1783920 - Ah, that changes the problem considerably. You can write a method to format the data the way you want and call that in place of `String.valueOf`. If you update your question and post the definition of the `LibraryUser` class, I can be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

your code should work fine:

```
LinkedList<String> l = new LinkedList<>();
        l.add("aaa");
        l.add("sdjs");
        ListIterator<String> itr = l.listIterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
```

above code prints:

> aaa
>   sdjs

Comment: Yea I know in normal circumstances but I am working with objects inside the linked list

Comment: FYI, String is an object, what object are you using ??

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to consider using the enhanced for-loop. Something like:

```
LinkedList<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();
list.add("abc");
list.add("def");
for(Object element: list){
    System.out.println(element);
}
```